# Add/ expand animation will cause unwanted UIScrollView scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I notice that, if I perform add/ expand animation within an `UIScrollView`, it will cause unwanted scrolling behavior, when the `UIScrollView` fill with enough content to become scroll-able.

As you can see in the following animation, initially, the add/ expand animation works just fine.

When we have added enough item till the `UIScrollView` scrollable, whenever a new item is added, and `UIScrollView` will first perform scroll down, and then scroll up again!

[image]

My expectation is that, the `UIScrollView` should remain static, when add/ expand animation is performed.

Here's the code which performs add/ expand animation.

### Add/ expand animation

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    let customView = CustomView.instanceFromNib()
    
    customView.hide()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
    // Clear off horizontal swipe in animation caused by addArrangedSubview
    stackView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    customView.show()
    // Perform expand animation.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.stackView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Here's the constraint setup of the `UIScrollView` & added custom view item

### Constraint setup

[image]

### Custom view

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    private var zeroHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var borderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = stackView.frame.height / 2
        borderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        zeroHeightConstraint = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = false
    }
    
    func hide() {
        zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
    func show() {
        zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = false
    }
}
```

---

Here's the complete source code

https://github.com/yccheok/add-expand-animation-in-scroll-view

**Do you have any idea why such problem occur, and we can fix such?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way stack views arrange their subviews, animation can be problematic.

One approach that you may find works better is to embed the stack view in a "container" view.

That way, you can use the `.isHidden` property when adding an arranged subview, and allow the animation to update the "container" view:

[image]

The "add view" function now becomes (I added a Bool so we can skip the animation on the initial add in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
func addCustomView(_ animated: Bool) {
    let customView = CustomView.instanceFromNib()
    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
    customView.isHidden = true
    
    if animated {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                customView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    } else {
        customView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

And we can get rid of all of the `hide() / show()` and `zeroHeightConstraint` in the custom view class:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var borderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        borderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = borderView.bounds.height * 0.5
    }
}
```

Since it's a bit difficult to clearly show everything here, I forked your project with the changes: https://github.com/DonMag/add-expand-animation-in-scroll-view

---

**Edit**

Another "quirk" of animating a stack view shows up when adding the first arranged subview (also, when removing the last one).

One way to get around that is to add an empty view as the first subview.

So, for this example, in `viewDidLoad()` *before* adding an instance of `CustomView`:

```
let v = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
```

This will make the first arranged subview a zero-height view (so it won't be visible).

Then, if you're implementing *removing* custom views, just make sure you don't remove that first, empty view.

If your stack view has `.spacing = 0` noting else is needed.

If your stack view has a non-zero spacing, add another line:

```
let v = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
stackView.setCustomSpacing(0, after: v)
```

Comment: Thanks! I notice I can avoid the "jumpy" issue, by using `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `UIView.animate`. I prefer your solution, which doesn't require show/ hide function from custom view. The only problem I notice, when the animation is performed on empty stackview, a horizontal animation will be performed during the 1st time. I was wondering, is there a way to avoid such? - https://i.imgur.com/bsoRjHf.mp4

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: That was a very neat hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research on this and the consensus was to update the `isHidden` and `alpha` properties when inserting a view with animations.

In CustomView:

```
func hide() {
    alpha = 0.0
    isHidden = true
    zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = true
}

func show() {
    alpha = 1.0
    isHidden = false
    zeroHeightConstraint.isActive = false
}
```

In your view controller:

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    let customView = CustomView.instanceFromNib()
    customView.hide()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
    self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 00.5) {
        customView.show()
        self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Also, the constraints in your storyboard aren't totally correct. You are seeing a red constraint error because autolayout doesn't know the height of your stackView. You can give it a fake height and make sure that "Remove at build time" is checked.

Also, get rid of your scrollView contentView height constraint defined as `View.height >= Frame Layout Guide.height`. Autolayout doesn't need to know the height, it just needs to know how subviews inside of the contentView stack up to define its vertical content size.

Everything else looks pretty good.